# Take screenshot of multi-monitor setup

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm taking a screenshot using this line

```
screen = QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())
```

but apparently that doesn't grab the full desktop if the user has several monitors.

Is there a way to grab the desktop of all monitors into a single image?

Comment: A search for [qt screenshot multi monitor](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=qt+screenshot+multi+monitor) provides a Qt-interest thread [dual monitor screenshot](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2007-08/msg00011.html); then the question becomes just joining them into a single image.

Comment: Also have a look at QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry and QDesktopWidget::screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [blog](http://atkit.com/dev/qt-dev/grabbing-multi-monitor-screenshot-qt/), just add the x, y, width, and height to grab the full desktop.

Comment: Your link is bad. Can you please re-find?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to loop over `QApplication.screens()` and grab them one at a time like so...

*Note: using Python 3.8 and PyQt5*

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
for screen in QApplication.screens():
    screen_path = os.path.expanduser(f"~/Desktop/{screen.name()}.jpg")
    screen.grabWindow(0).save(screen_path, 'jpg')  
    # grabWindow(0) means full screen
    # for area use following format; x=0, y=0, w=-1, h=-1
```